# Save file Excel using Openpyx without loosing data

Tags: python, copy, openpyxl

Using this command, unfortunately it always creates that file for me, losing the previous data:

`Account.save("Ex.xlsx")`

The command: `SaveCopyAs` not work with a workbook

I would simply like to replicate the `SaveCopyAs` command on python to save my excel file after writing and updating it. Unfortunately with the `save` command, I delete all the previous content

Comment: Simply reposting a question that has been closed is not a good way to get an answer.

Comment: The question has been changed to be clearer. I would simply like to replicate the `SaveCopyAs` command on python to save my excel file after writing and updating it. Unfortunately with the `save` command, I delete all the previous content. I hope this time, I was clear

Comment: I don't see any openpyxl code. Looks like you're hoping someone will write everything for you. Good luck with that!

Comment: `Example=Workbook()
Example["Sheet"].title="Sheet"
sh1=Sheet.active
sh1['B2'].value=mail


Example.save("Jungle.xlsx")



`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `Example=Workbook()`, you are making a new file. That means when you execute `Example.save("Jungle.xlsx")`, you are overwriting the original file. Instead, you should use `Example = load_workbook('Jungle.xlsx')` to read the contents of the original so that `Example.save("Jungle.xlsx")` can act like an update.

See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file for more details.